# Three 20 TTButton with remote image

Tags: iphone, button, three20

I have an array of images which I want to display as buttons in a table View. Currently I am using TTButton for showing those buttons. I have set the image using

```
[theButton setImage:imageUrl forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But once the image is downloaded, it is not showing up in the view. Can anyone help me out with this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using TTThumbView for imitating the same. Hope that helps anyone who is trying the same.

Answer (score 1):

How are you initializing the button? Try using one of the styles, such as:

```
TTButton *imageButton = [TTButton buttonWithStyle:@"thumbView:"];
```

The styles tell the images where to go. If you don't specify a style then you won't get an image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this......

```
        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:image];

        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

And then assign the image:

```
       [theButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: The button used is of class TTButton (from three20 framework). It takes only the image URL for setImage method and not the image as such.